# Android Studio: How to Group Modules?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am studying the multiple modules support in Android Studio and exploring its many options. [Reading the official doc from IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#grouping-modules) I learned that you can group modules using two approaches:

- explicit module groups;
- qualified names.

So I went into **[Android Studio → Preferences → Build, Execution, Deployment → Gradle → Project-level settings → Group Modules]** and found the following configuration:

[image: android_studio_group_modules]

However, even selecting the option "using qualified names" and giving qualified names to my modules, they aren't grouped:

[image]

I tried also to create an explicit module group, going into **[File → Project structure... → Modules → Context menu (right click)]** but nothing happens (no context menu!).

So my question is:

- How I can create a group of modules using Android Studio?

Thank you very much.